# Is there a node executable shipped with vscode?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

When I use the Remote Extension in vscode, I get a `.vscode-server` directory. Inside, I can find a node executable, e.g. in `~/.vscode-server/some-random-string/node`.

I figured this out by testing the following minimal vscode extension:

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('test.helloworld', () => {
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage(process.argv[0]); 
    });
    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}
export function deactivate() {}
```

Running the same extension *without the Remote extension*, e.g. within Windows, the same extension would show me that I am running vscode from:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe
```

My question is: **is there a `node` executable available somewhere within `vscode` (not using Remote Extension) and how to find its path reliably from a vscode extension?**

This is what I see in the `Microsoft VS Code` directory:

Directories:

- bin
- locales
- policies
- resources
- tools

as well as the Code.exe, and other irrelevant files. I looked everywhere but couldn't find any `node` executable.

There is also a `~/.vscode` directory in my home folder, where you can find `extensions`, and an empty `cli` folder.

Comment: I have no authoritative answer for your question, but I think there's no Node.js. Instead VS Code is based on Electron, which is itself a native binary and provides the necessary APIs for accessing the OS resources like disks, IO and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the [answer is no](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-tutorial#:%7E:text=Visual%20Studio%20Code%20has%20support,Node.js%20for%20your%20platform.):

> Visual Studio Code has support for the JavaScript and TypeScript languages out-of-the-box as well as Node.js debugging. However, to run a Node.js application, you will need to install the Node.js runtime on your machine.

Note that the node executable in the Remote environment appears to be installed by the [vscode server service](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/vscode-server).